# Google Sheets: BigQuery Connect --> How to Make Connected Pivot Table and Connected Chart Using Apps Script Only?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-bigquery, pivot-table

I am currently using BigQuery Connect to connect my Google Sheet to BigQuery.  This connection is done in AppsScript code using:

```
SpreadsheetApp.newDataSourceSpec().asBigQuery()
```

MyAppsScript code pulls in about 500 rows of "preview data" in a "connected sheet" tab. Let's say my actual data has about 20,000 rows of data.  I want to use **only AppsScript code** to create a connected pivot table and connected chart off of my BigQuery connected input dataset.

This is so that when I set the automatic daily refresh my pivot tables and charts also automatically refresh.

Essentially I want my entire Google sheet to be generated from AppsScript code from beginning to end.

I've been searching documentation, Google, and StackOverflow for awhile but haven't had any luck.

Any suggestions or links to samples or documentation?

Comment: I am not familiar but have you tried [`setRowLimit(rowLimit)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-table#setrowlimitrowlimit)?

Answer (score 1):

As you have used [SpreadsheetApp.newDataSourceSpec().asBigQuery()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-spec-builder) to connect Google Sheet to BigQuery, [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) method can be used to access the connected sheet and then use [refreshData()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-pivot-table#refreshData()) methods to update the data. This method [createDataSourcePivotTable(dataSource)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createdatasourcepivottabledatasource) creates and configures a new data source pivot table. You can also try the `Sheet` class to create a [newChart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#newChart()) method.

I will post this as a Community Wiki since this is a possible workaround which can be edited by anyone within this community. Please feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.