# Schedule auto refresh in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that connects to the bigquery and there are one extract table and one pivot table linked to that base table.
I was trying to set up an auto refresh in Gsheet so that all the data could get refreshed at 2pm every day. But, it keeps giving me an error.

```
Scheduled refresh could not be completed
Reason:An issue with some connected objects (e.g. pivot table, chart, etc)
Go to the file and check error messages
```

But it works fine when I manually refresh it. Does anyone know the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76902024/google-sheets-bigquery-connect-how-to-make-connected-pivot-table-and-connec?rq=2) that may be similar to your issue. Let me know if this helps.